# Weird corruption of data

Tags: arrays, c, file, struct, corruption

Eow, I was working on a program which would take in a .txt with a list of football matches i.e team, scores, date etc. and store these in a struct *array. After this I'd run through the matches and assign points to the teams based on win/draw/loss. However when testing that everything was running smooth i ran into a problem, im not the most experienced coder but 2 me it looks like some corruption, and i simply cannot fathom how it gets corrupted. When i run the function "fill match array" and print out my struct *array over the matches it works perfectly, however after running the function "allocate team space" and then printing out the struct *array over the matches the data is really corrupted and it looks like it prints the entire .txt and then the "rest" of what its supposed to print, but with some corruption here and there.

**Now that im changing the prints to show the problem for u guys i get a different corruption, only the first line of my match struct * array seems corrupted now**

Any help would be much appreciated =)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MSIZE 132
#define TSIZE 12

typedef struct match
{
    char weekday[10], date[10], time[10], home[10], away[10], spectators[10];
    int home_goal, away_goal;
} match;

typedef struct team
{
    char teamname[4];
    int point, goals, goals_against, goals_sum;
} team;

void fill_match_array(match *match_array[MSIZE]);
void allocate_space_team(team *team_array[TSIZE]);
void fill_team_array(team *team_array[TSIZE], match *match_array[MSIZE]);


int main(void){
    match *match_array[MSIZE];
    team *team_array[TSIZE];

    fill_match_array(match_array);

    printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < MSIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%s | %s | %s | %s | %s | - | %d | - | %d | %s\n", match_array[i]->weekday, match_array[i]->date, match_array[i]->time, match_array[i]->home, match_array[i]->away, match_array[i]->home_goal, match_array[i]->away_goal, match_array[i]->spectators);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    
    allocate_space_team(team_array);
    fill_team_array(team_array, match_array);

    for (int i = 0; i < MSIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%s | %s | %s | %s | %s | - | %d | - | %d | %s\n", match_array[i]->weekday, match_array[i]->date, match_array[i]->time, match_array[i]->home, match_array[i]->away, match_array[i]->home_goal, match_array[i]->away_goal, match_array[i]->spectators);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    printf("%s | %s | %s | %s | %s | - | %d | - | %d | %s\n", match_array[0]->weekday, match_array[0]->date, match_array[0]->time, match_array[0]->home, match_array[0]->away, match_array[0]->home_goal, match_array[0]->away_goal, match_array[0]->spectators);
    
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TSIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%s | %d | %d | %d | %d\n", team_array[i]->teamname, team_array[i]->point, team_array[i]->goals, team_array[i]->goals_against, team_array[i]->goals_sum);
    }



    return 0;
}

void fill_match_array(match *match_array[MSIZE]){
    FILE *output_file_pointer;
    output_file_pointer = fopen("kampe-2020-2021.txt", "r");

    char x[5], y[5], home_goal[10], away_goal[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < MSIZE; i++)
    {
        match_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(match));
        fscanf(output_file_pointer, "%s     %s %s     %s %s %s     %s %s %s     %s", match_array[i]->weekday, match_array[i]->date, match_array[i]->time, match_array[i]->home, x, match_array[i]->away, home_goal, y, away_goal, match_array[i]->spectators);
        match_array[i]->home_goal = atoi(home_goal);
        match_array[i]->away_goal = atoi(away_goal);
        //printf("%s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %d | %s | %d | %s\n", match_array[i]->weekday, match_array[i]->date, match_array[i]->time, match_array[i]->home, x, match_array[i]->away, match_array[i]->home_goal, y, match_array[i]->away_goal, match_array[i]->spectators);
    }

    fclose(output_file_pointer);
}

void allocate_space_team(team *team_array[TSIZE]){
    for (int i = 0; i < TSIZE + 1; i++)
    {
        team_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(team));
        team_array[i]->goals = 0;
        team_array[i]->goals_against = 0;
        team_array[i]->goals_sum = 0;
        team_array[i]->point = 0;
    }
    strcpy(team_array[0]->teamname, "SDR");
    strcpy(team_array[1]->teamname, "ACH");
    strcpy(team_array[2]->teamname, "LBK");
    strcpy(team_array[3]->teamname, "BIF");
    strcpy(team_array[4]->teamname, "OB");
    strcpy(team_array[5]->teamname, "AGF");
    strcpy(team_array[6]->teamname, "FCM");
    strcpy(team_array[7]->teamname, "FCK");
    strcpy(team_array[8]->teamname, "RFC");
    strcpy(team_array[9]->teamname, "VB");
    strcpy(team_array[10]->teamname, "AaB");
    strcpy(team_array[11]->teamname, "FCN");
}

void fill_team_array(team *team_array[TSIZE], match *match_array[MSIZE]){
    for (int i = 0; i < TSIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MSIZE; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(team_array[i]->teamname, match_array[j]->home) == 0)
            {
                team_array[i]->goals += match_array[j]->home_goal;
                team_array[i]->goals_against += match_array[j]->away_goal;
                if (match_array[j]->home_goal > match_array[j]->away_goal)
                {
                    team_array[i]->point += 3;
                }
                else if (match_array[j]->home_goal == match_array[j]->away_goal)
                {
                    team_array[i]->point += 1;
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(team_array[i]->teamname, match_array[j]->away) == 0)
            {
                team_array[i]->goals += match_array[j]->away_goal;
                team_array[i]->goals_against += match_array[j]->home_goal;
                if (match_array[j]->away_goal > match_array[j]->home_goal)
                {
                    team_array[i]->point += 3;
                }
                else if (match_array[j]->home_goal == match_array[j]->away_goal)
                {
                    team_array[i]->point += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        team_array[i]->goals_sum = team_array[i]->goals - team_array[i]->goals_against;
    }
}
```

**txt.file -> names ->"kampe-2020-2021.txt"**

```
Fre     11/09 19.00     SDR - FCM     2 - 0     2210
Son     13/09 14.00     ACH - RFC     0 - 3     1216
Son     13/09 14.00     LBK - AaB     0 - 0     2138
Son     13/09 16.00     BIF - FCN     3 - 2     6775
Son     13/09 18.00     OB - FCK      3 - 2     4315
Man     14/09 19.00     AGF - VB      4 - 2     7547
Lor     19/09 15.30     FCM - LBK     1 - 0     300  
Son     20/09 14.00     FCK - BIF     1 - 2     277  
Son     20/09 14.00     OB - FCN      1 - 1     300  
Son     20/09 16.00     RFC - AGF     1 - 1     300  
Son     20/09 18.00     VB - SDR      4 - 1     350  
Man     21/09 19.00     AaB - ACH     1 - 0     280  
Lor     26/09 17.00     FCM - RFC     1 - 0     300  
Son     27/09 14.00     AGF - OB      4 - 2     300  
Son     27/09 14.00     SDR - AaB     3 - 1     300  
Son     27/09 16.00     BIF - ACH     2 - 1     300  
Son     27/09 18.00     VB - FCK      2 - 2     350  
Man     28/09 19.00     FCN - LBK     4 - 1     300  
Fre     02/10 19.00     RFC - BIF     1 - 2     300  
Son     04/10 14.00     LBK - SDR     2 - 2     300  
Son     04/10 14.00     OB - VB       0 - 1     300  
Son     04/10 16.00     AaB - AGF     1 - 1     280  
Son     04/10 18.00     ACH - FCM     2 - 2     300  
Son     04/10 20.00     FCK - FCN     3 - 2     220  
Lor     17/10 16.00     FCM - OB      3 - 1     300  
Son     18/10 14.00     AGF - ACH     3 - 0     300  
Son     18/10 14.00     VB - LBK      3 - 2     350  
Son     18/10 16.00     SDR - BIF     2 - 0     300  
Son     18/10 18.00     FCK - AaB     1 - 2     242  
Man     19/10 19.00     FCN - RFC     1 - 0     300  
Fre     23/10 19.00     LBK - OB      0 - 3     300  
Lor     24/10 18.00     BIF - FCM     2 - 3     300  
Son     25/10 14.00     ACH - FCN     1 - 1     300  
Son     25/10 16.00     RFC - SDR     1 - 2     300  
Son     25/10 18.00     AGF - FCK     0 - 1     300  
Man     26/10 19.00     AaB - VB      1 - 3     300  
Fre     30/10 19.00     VB - RFC      0 - 3     350  
Lor     31/10 16.00     FCN - FCM     4 - 1     300  
Son     01/11 14.00     OB - ACH      1 - 0     300  
Son     01/11 16.00     FCK - LBK     4 - 2     247  
Son     01/11 18.00     AaB - BIF     2 - 1     300  
Man     02/11 19.00     SDR - AGF     1 - 1     300  
Fre     06/11 19.00     RFC - AaB     1 - 2     300  
Son     08/11 14.00     FCN - VB      1 - 1     300  
Son     08/11 14.00     LBK - AGF     1 - 2     300  
Son     08/11 16.00     BIF - OB      3 - 1     300  
Son     08/11 18.00     FCM - FCK     4 - 0     300  
Son     08/11 20.00     ACH - SDR     0 - 3     300  
Fre     20/11 19.00     LBK - ACH     1 - 1     300  
Son     22/11 14.00     OB - SDR      1 - 1     300  
Son     22/11 14.00     AaB - FCN     1 - 1     300  
Son     22/11 16.00     AGF - FCM     1 - 2     300  
Son     22/11 18.00     VB - BIF      0 - 2     350  
Man     23/11 19.00     FCK - RFC     1 - 2     246  
Fre     27/11 19.00     RFC - OB      2 - 1     300  
Lor     28/11 16.00     FCM - AaB     0 - 0     300  
Son     29/11 14.00     ACH - VB      3 - 1     300  
Son     29/11 16.00     SDR - FCK     1 - 3     300  
Son     29/11 18.00     FCN - AGF     3 - 1     300  
Man     30/11 19.00     BIF - LBK     4 - 1     300  
Fre     04/12 19.00     OB - AaB      2 - 1     300  
Lor     05/12 16.00     VB - FCM      0 - 2     350  
Son     06/12 14.00     SDR - FCN     2 - 1     300  
Son     06/12 16.00     FCK - ACH     2 - 0     226  
Son     06/12 18.00     LBK - RFC     0 - 3     300  
Man     07/12 19.00     AGF - BIF     3 - 1     300  
Fre     11/12 19.00     RFC - VB      3 - 1     300  
Son     13/12 14.00     ACH - AGF     1 - 2     300  
Son     13/12 14.00     AaB - LBK     3 - 2     300  
Son     13/12 16.00     FCN - FCK     0 - 1     300  
Son     13/12 18.00     BIF - SDR     2 - 1     300  
Man     14/12 19.00     OB - FCM      1 - 1     300  
Son     20/12 14.00     SDR - RFC     0 - 1     300  
Son     20/12 14.00     LBK - VB      0 - 0     300  
Son     20/12 16.00     AGF - AaB     3 - 0     300  
Son     20/12 18.00     FCK - OB      1 - 1     242  
Son     20/12 20.00     ACH - BIF     1 - 2     300  
Man     21/12 19.00     FCM - FCN     3 - 1     300  
Tir     02/02 18.00     RFC - ACH     3 - 0     0    
Tir     02/02 20.00     VB - AGF      0 - 0     0    
Ons     03/02 18.00     OB - LBK      0 - 1     0    
Ons     03/02 20.00     AaB - FCK     2 - 3     0    
Tor     04/02 18.00     FCM - SDR     1 - 2     0    
Tor     04/02 20.00     FCN - BIF     0 - 1     0    
Son     07/02 14.00     SDR - VB      0 - 1     0    
Son     07/02 14.00     FCN - OB      0 - 2     0    
Son     07/02 16.00     ACH - FCK     0 - 2     0    
Son     07/02 18.00     AGF - LBK     1 - 0     0    
Son     07/02 20.00     BIF - AaB     1 - 1     0    
Man     08/02 19.00     RFC - FCM     1 - 2     0    
Son     14/02 14.00     AaB - RFC     0 - 0     0    
Son     14/02 14.00     VB - FCN      2 - 2     0    
Son     14/02 16.00     LBK - BIF     0 - 4     0    
Son     14/02 18.00     FCM - ACH     1 - 0     0    
Son     14/02 20.00     OB - AGF      0 - 0     0    
Man     15/02 19.00     FCK - SDR     3 - 2     0    
Fre     19/02 19.00     AaB - FCM     0 - 2     0    
Son     21/02 14.00     RFC - FCN     1 - 1     0    
Son     21/02 14.00     ACH - OB      0 - 0     0    
Son     21/02 16.00     AGF - SDR     2 - 0     0    
Son     21/02 18.00     BIF - VB      2 - 1     0    
Man     22/02 19.00     LBK - FCK     2 - 2     0    
Fre     26/02 19.00     VB - ACH      0 - 0     0    
Son     28/02 14.00     OB - RFC      2 - 1     0    
Son     28/02 14.00     FCN - AaB     2 - 2     0    
Son     28/02 16.00     FCK - AGF     3 - 3     0    
Son     28/02 18.00     FCM - BIF     1 - 0     0    
Man     01/03 19.00     SDR - LBK     1 - 4     0    
Ons     03/03 18.00     AGF - FCN     0 - 1     0    
Ons     03/03 18.00     ACH - AaB     2 - 1     0    
Ons     03/03 20.00     FCK - VB      2 - 1     0    
Tor     04/03 18.00     SDR - OB      1 - 1     0    
Tor     04/03 18.00     LBK - FCM     2 - 0     0    
Tor     04/03 20.00     BIF - RFC     0 - 0     0    
Son     07/03 12.00     RFC - LBK     1 - 2     0    
Son     07/03 14.00     BIF - FCK     2 - 1     0    
Son     07/03 16.00     FCM - AGF     0 - 1     0    
Son     07/03 18.00     FCN - ACH     2 - 2     0    
Son     07/03 20.00     VB - OB       2 - 0     0    
Man     08/03 19.00     AaB - SDR     1 - 0     0    
Fre     12/03 19.00     LBK - FCN     0 - 3     0    
Son     14/03 14.00     SDR - ACH     2 - 0     0    
Son     14/03 14.00     VB - AaB      0 - 2     0    
Son     14/03 16.00     OB - BIF      0 - 3     0    
Son     14/03 18.00     FCK - FCM     0 - 0     0    
Man     15/03 19.00     AGF - RFC     1 - 1     0    
Son     21/03 17.00     BIF - AGF     1 - 1     0    
Son     21/03 17.00     FCM - VB      5 - 0     0    
Son     21/03 17.00     RFC - FCK     2 - 1     0    
Son     21/03 17.00     ACH - LBK     1 - 2     0    
Son     21/03 17.00     FCN - SDR     2 - 1     0    
Son     21/03 17.00     AaB - OB      0 - 2     0
```

Comment: Use a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help you find the cause of the issue (likely buffer overflow or other mem corruption).

Comment: Help yourself by doing basic error checking. For example, check the return value of `fscanf`.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < TSIZE + 1; i++)` This will cause a buffer overflow. For `team_array[TSIZE]` the max valid index is `TSZIZE-1` but the loop uses `TSIZE` as the last index. The condition should be `i < TSIZE` (BTW, this is something valgrind will instantly point out to you).

Comment: @kaylum omg, been working on different program that uses a lot of "size+1" and i guess turtlebrain took over. Cant belive i didn't spot it. This was it tyvm <3

Comment: Glad that helps. But really really do suggest you learn to effectively use tools like valgrind and debuggers. They will save you lots of time and not using them is like trying to build a house with a spoon (ok, perhaps that's a bit exaggerated :-)

Comment: @kaylum Ye I will, probably a lot less of me hitting my head against the wall.